# the number of elements in basis is greater than or equal to the dimension of the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose a vector space $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the basis of it is $\boldsymbol{\phi} = \{\phi_1,\cdots,\phi_m\}$, where $\phi_i\in \mathbb{R}^k$.

I wonder the relationship between $k$, $m$ and $n$?

Is the following statements correct?

- The dimension of $V$ equals $m$.
- $m\le n$ always holds since $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- $n\ge k \ge m$?

Comment: A basis is a subset of the vector space, so every element $\phi _i$ has to be an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So $n$ is exactly equal to $k$. Also the number of elements of the basis is by definition the dimension of the vector space. Edit: I thought you meant $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, but I see now you wrote an element of. Without more information this question is impossible to answer/doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why do you write $V\in \mathbb R^n$? Literally that says $V$ is an **element** of $\mathbb R^n$. And how do you know $n\neq k$? Is there some further story behind this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your comments and apologize for my mistakes. I've updated the question, please check it out.

Answer (score 4):

There's too many misconceptions to address in a mere comment, so have a community wiki answer.

As far as I can tell, $V$ is supposed to be a vector subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or possibly $\Bbb{R}^k$). It is incorrect to say $V \in \Bbb{R}^n$, because this suggests that $V$ is an element of $\Bbb{R}^n$. That is, $V$ is just a single vector; an $n$-tuple of real numbers. Instead, you should write "$V \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ is a subspace", or as it is sometimes written, $V \le \Bbb{R}^n$ (though, in my experience, not everyone knows this notation without some prompting).

Now, some important things to keep in mind:

> If a basis of a vector space exists, then every basis of that vector space has the same number of elements. The number of elements in every basis of the space is the **dimension** of the space.

The vector space $\Bbb{R}^2$ has dimension $2$, because it is easy to verify that $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ is a basis for it. By the above result, every basis of $\Bbb{R}^2$ has $2$ elements, so the dimension is indeed $2$.

Note that the dimension is not found simply by reading the little superscript $2$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$. It is possible, for example, to find $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^3$. For example, the subset
$$V = \{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 : x + y + z = 0\}$$
is a subspace with dimension $2$. Note that vectors in $V$ take the form
$$(x, y, -x - y) = (x, 0, -x) + (0, y, -y) = x(1, 0, -1) + y(0, 1, -1).$$
That is, they belong to the span of $\{(1, 0, -1), (0, 1, -1)\}$. This set is also linearly independent, so it forms a basis for $V$. Hence, all bases have $2$ elements, making it a $2$-dimensional subspace.

All the vectors in $V$ and the preceding set belong to $\Bbb{R}^3$. We can see the little $3$ superscript, but that doesn't tell us the dimension.

It does mean, however that the dimension is **at most** $3$. Indeed, the following holds:

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space of dimension $n$, and $W \subseteq V$ is a subspace. Then $W$ is finite-dimensional, and has dimension $k \le n$. Moreover, if $k = n$, then $W = V$.

So, if you have a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$, yes, the dimension will be less than or equal to $n$. If you know the subspace is proper (i.e. it doesn't contain all of $\Bbb{R}^n$), the you know the dimension is *strictly* less than $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much Theo for your comprehensive answer. I'm currently reviewing linear algebra so apologize for my mistakes.

Comment: I've updated my question according to your answer. However one question remains: Is $k$ always equals to $m$ or $k$ could be greater than $m$.

Comment: Taking your example, I believe $n = 3, m=2$ and $k =3$. So $k$ could be larger than $m$ but must less than or equal to $n$. Is that right？

Comment: Your question contains something of a contradiction, which is that you can't have a basis for $V \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ that consists of vectors $\phi_k \in \Bbb{R}^k$ (unless $k = n$). A basis for $V$ must be a subset of $V$, which is a subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$. This means that all the elements of any basis of $V$ must consist of $n$-tuples of real numbers, not $k$-tuples of real numbers. The parameter $k$ doesn't make sense, unless it's just another name for $n$. The parameter $m$ refers to the size of the basis, i.e. the dimension of $V$, so as previously discussed, we will have $m \le n = k$.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much!